# C#/Unity: NPCs Skipping Lines of Dialogue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a Dialogue Manager to handle NPC speech in my game, and I'm running into some trouble.

I have two NPC's; if I only talk to one, it'll go through all of their lines, no problem (each NPC has five lines of code, triggered by the PC going up to them and pressing Space). However, if I talk to NPC1, then NPC2, it will only ever display NPC2's speech, even if I go back to NPC1.

NPC.cs

```
public class NPC : Character {
    private bool charInRange;
    public Dialogue dialogue;
    public bool talkedTo = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        charInRange = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //if player is in range and presses space, triggers NPC dialogue
        if (charInRange && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            TriggerDialogue();
        }
    }

    //if Player gameObject is in NPC collider, player is in range
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            charInRange = true;
        }
    }

    //if player exits NPC collider, player is not in range
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            charInRange = false;
        }
    }

    //if NPC has been talked to before, displays next sentence; if not, loads dialogue and displays first sentence
    private void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        if (!talkedTo)
        {
            talkedTo = true;
            FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
        }
        else
        {
            FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().DisplayNextSentence();
        }
    }
}
```

DialogueManager.cs

```
public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour {

private Queue<string> sentences;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

//loads a queue with lines from Dialogue and displays first sentence
public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
{
    sentences = new Queue<string>();

    foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
    {
        sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
    }

    DisplayNextSentence();
}

//displays next sentence in the queue
public void DisplayNextSentence()
{
    Debug.Log(sentences.Count);

    //if no more sentences in the queue, end the dialogue
    if(sentences.Count == 0)
    {
        EndDialogue();
        return;
    }

    string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
    Debug.Log(sentence);
}

//ends dialogue
private void EndDialogue()
{
    Debug.Log("CONVERSATION OVER");
}
}
```

I know what the issue is: once NPC2 is talked to, talkedTo in NPC.cs flips, NPC2's dialogue starts, and NPC1's dialogue queue is wiped out. Then, it simply displays NPC2's next sentence, regardless of which collider the player is in. My problem is, I'm not sure how to resolve this. Should I be storing specific dialogue in specific NPC's? If so, how do I do that?

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are a few issues here... the first issue is it doesnt appear you can retalk to the NPC twice in a row.  Perhaps pass the NPC to the DialogueManager when you are talking to them and then at EndDialogue, reset the TalkTo to false?

Comment: When you are no longer colliding, you should also probably set the TalkTo To false as well...  and clear your DialogueManager.

Comment: You can talk to a character twice in a row; the issue is that there's only one queue that's being shared between two NPC's in the StartDialogue() function. Is there a way for each to have its own queue, and for them to be tracked separately?

Comment: yes you can store the queue on each NPC, and just have the Dialogue system show the next message in the queue when you talk to the NP instead of having the NPC call a start on the Dialogue system, and having the dialogue system store its queue of the dialogues the NPC sent

Comment: Aha! I knew I was close! Storing the queue on the NPC works brilliantly. Thanks for your help @Eddge!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Eddge in the comments:

> yes you can store the queue on each NPC, and just have the Dialogue
>   system show the next message in the queue when you talk to the NP
>   instead of having the NPC call a start on the Dialogue system, and
>   having the dialogue system store its queue of the dialogues the NPC
>   sent

Thank you!